# Is sodium acetate a neutral or a basic salt?

Tags: acid-base

I read somewhere that salts which do not contain a replaceable hydrogen or hydroxyl group are classified as normal salts. But I also know that strong base-weak acid salts are basic in nature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normal salts do not have to be neutral, and vice versa. There are two different features of a salt: **(1)** containing a replaceable hydrogen, and **(2)** making an acidic solution in water. They are not necessarily related. For example:

- $\ce{NaHSO4}$ has both.
- $\ce{NaHCO3}$ has the first and **not** the second (in fact, being a salt of a strong base and a weak acid, it has to be basic in nature, as you correctly recall).
- On the other hand, $\ce{CuSO4}$ is partially hydrolyzed in water solution and hence has the second feature, but not the first.
- To make the picture complete, $\ce{NaCl}$ has neither.

Likewise, the opposite features of **(1)** having a hydroxy group and **(2)** making a basic solution in water are even less related. For example:

- $\ce{Cu2(OH)2CO3}$ has the first feature, but not the second (for it is not even soluble in water).
- $\ce{CH3COONa}$ is partially hydrolyzed in water solution and hence has the second feature, but not the first.
- $\ce{MgCl2}$ and $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ form several basic salt phases with both features ([*J. Chem. Eng. Data* **2017**, *62* (4), 1384–1396](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jced.6b00928)).  They are only sparingly soluble but still form measurably alkaline solutions, especially when warmed.
- $\ce{MgSO4}$ has neither.

Comment: What about the particular case in the question?

Comment: Sodium acetate **is** hidden somewhere in my answer.

Comment: Okay so I get it...a salt is only neutral when it follows neither 1 not 2. Thanks :)

Comment: No, a salt is _neutral_ when it doesn't follow 2, and _normal_ when it doesn't follow 1. These things may or may not coincide.

Comment: I find it *very* hard to get the idea. You are defining those "features", but what follows from them? What do you mean CuSO4 "hydrolyzes" in water? If you mean the sulfate ion, it's a rather weak base, with pKa of $HSO_4^-$ of ~2. How should I know the acetate ion is basic, without knowing the pKa of acetic acid?

Comment: Well, then chemistry is hard. Now to the point: sulfate ion does not hydrolyze in water, since it is a very weak base, like you said. As for the acetate ion and its basicity: without knowing the pKa of acetic acid, you wouldn't know that.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by "CuSO4 hydrolyzes", and how that makes the solution acidic. Copper sulfate *dissolves* in water, right. And now? $Cu2+$ hydrate is notably acidic? That's not what you wrote, and I don't even immediately know where to look it up.

Comment: When we say that a certain salt hydrolyzes, it isn't clear without context whether we mean the hydrolysis of the cation, or anion, or both. In the case of CuSO4, it is the cation.

Answer (score 0):

Since sodium acetate is the salt formed from sodium hydroxide (a strong base) and acetic acid (a weak acid) a solution of the salt should be alkaline.